# Use CSS to hide all tags but certain ones w/ no ability to add class

Tags: css

I would like to do something like this....

```
body{
display:none;
}
#signIn_form_section{
display:inline;
}
```

Of course this does not work but I am looking for something similar. Basically I want to whitelist tags that are allowed to display.

Added html in jfiddle....

[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/j77w8/)

Basically I just want the form and non-hidden input fields to show up.

Comment: When parent element is hidden, all its child elements are hidden too!

Comment: .tag {display:none;} .tag.viewable {display:inline;}.....

Comment: Just give those elements you want to hide a specific class and set that class to display:none

Comment: why not just use a class. `.hide { display: none; }` Is there a reason as to why you can't?

Comment: Are you trying to make a modal box or something ?

Comment: Thanks guys I do not have control over the HTML FYI

Comment: @ashley I cannot control HTML

Comment: Are you allowed enough control to post the HTML here and explain in more depth your reasoning?

Comment: @Engineer I get that I just wanted to psuedo display what I am trying to do

Comment: @YaMo sure I am taking the html from a site and making a mobile interface but I would like to use the existing HTML. However, there is a lot of crap I don't need and very little I do. I could create my own HTML (which I have done) and do the post request but I would rather use theirs just with only the elements I need showing.

Comment: It would be great to put that html in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) in order to see what's the best way of doing this in this particular case

Comment: @Brewal the HTML is from here... https://members.poolplayers.com/

Comment: @Jackie, if that is what you are trying to do, I think you are better off hiding specific things (perhaps a LOT of specific things) rather than whitelisting specific things.  It's much safer.

Comment: Another solution would be to use javascript and clean your html with keeping only the desired elements.

Comment: @andi yeah that is what I am guessing I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution

Comment: The problem with this "whitelisting" is that you're likely to accidentally hide a parent element of what you are trying to show.  An element will not display unless it and all of its parents/ancestors are visible.

Comment: @andi I get that but it seems a lot easier to go back through and add one tag than remove 7 more that you find. But I believe this may be a limitation to CSS and not achievable.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a [working CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/exzyF) of how to do this. You need to be specific about the tag, such as `section` in this example, `*:not` does not work properly.

HTML:

```
<section>
  <article>
    <p>I am hidden</p>
  </article>
</section>

<section class="display">
  <article>
    <p>You can see me</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section:not(.display) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: The OP can't change the HTML

Comment: Using `section` was simply for illustration, the OP can use whatever they have to work with.

Comment: the OP cannot put the `.display` classes in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean:

```
 * {
     display: none;
 }
 #signIn_form_section{
     display:inline;
 }
```

However, I don't believe this is a good idea... Could you please develop your requirements? Why you need to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class `display` to elements that you want to display and do this to hide all the ones that don't have that class:

```
*:not(.display) {
    display: none;
}
```

However I would question why you want to do this.

It might make more sense to add a class `hidden` to elements you want to hide and do this instead:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? You could add an explanation. If the reason is because the OP cannot change HTML, that comment was added *after* I posted my answer. @Jackie, you posted a link to the site that you want to apply this to, but did not specify what you want to hide. If you tell us what you want to hide, that would help.

Comment: I don't think I initiated the down vote but this would require adding a class to all the elements that are supposed to be displayed. Although not initially made clear, because I am "screen scraping" I do not have the ability to add a class to the tag. This may work in a situation where you have control but is fairly taxing as it would have to be added to each tag (or not shown tag).

Answer (score 0):

First Set

```
div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video { display:none; }
```

then make a class and set it to `display:block;` add this class to those elements you want to show.

Comment: @Don Then you should share those ideas in comments so that I can also learn :)

Comment: Also no control over HTML so I can't add class

Comment: I think this way actually makes the most sense, based on the exact details of the question.  OP doesn't have control over HTML so can't add a "show" class, but could still do some sort of whitelist.

Comment: This approach is fragile due to the specificity of the tags. My [working solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19545342/630092) contains much less fragility.

Comment: the edited version may cause problems; I think the original was better.